# how to use the gridview in SharePoint 2013 Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model, sharepoint-hosted-app, gridview

I want know how to use the grid view in a SharePoint-hosted App. Can any one provide information on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use built-in server controls in a SharePoint-Hosted app. You just can't use any code-behind. The markup for the various data source and UI controls remains the same.

```
<SharePoint:SPDataSource ID="SPDataSource1" runat="server"            
    DataSourceMode="List"
    SelectCommand="<Query></Query>" >
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter name="ListName" DefaultValue="Contacts" />
    </SelectParameters>
</SharePoint:SPDataSource>
<SharePoint:SPGridView ID="SPGridView1" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    DataSourceID="SPDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <SharePoint:SPBoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Last Name" />
        <SharePoint:SPBoundField DataField="First Name" HeaderText="First Name" />
        <SharePoint:SPBoundField DataField="Company" HeaderText="Company" />
        <SharePoint:SPBoundField DataField="Business Phone" HeaderText="Work Phone" />
    </Columns>
</SharePoint:SPGridView>
```